# How to enable/disable button with a function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with my university project

It's a little game, 6 buttons for each players and 2 players so 12 buttons

There is number in each buttons, if a player has his 6 buttons at 0, he can't play

I have try some Public Function and i'm actually working with a very simple one but i think this is not the problem

My function is here
[image]

And in my form, the problem is here, i've tried many things but i don't know how do to that ... I read my lesson and I'm searching on the internet, i have no idea ..
[image]

Comment: Please **do not post pictures of code**.  In thcode shown, the return value is never set in the method.  With Option Strict On, there should be a warning

Answer (score 0):

If `possible` is `True` you don't re-enable the button.

You can simplify things.

```
Public Function PeutJouer(ByVal joueur As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim start As Integer = (joueur - 1) * 7
    For i As Integer = start To start + 5
        sum += tableau(i)
    Next
    Return sum <> 0
End Function
```

Then

```
Btn1P1.Enabled = PeutJouer(1)
```

Did you show all the relevant code? You are declaring `Dim tableau(12) As Integer` but the array is never filled with values. Probably `tableau` should be declared at the form level and not locally in this function. If you already have both, remove the local declaration, because it hides the one at form level. You also need to return the result from the function. I don't see this in your function.

Note that this

```
If x <> 0 Then
    booleanVariable = True
Else
    booleanVariable = True
End If
```

can be simplified to

```
booleanVariable = x <> 0
```

i.e., the condition is an expression yielding the Boolean result `True` or `False` already and you can use this value directly. When working with numeric values you don't write `If x + y = 1 Then r = 1 Else If x + y = 2 Then r = 2 ...`. You simply write `r = x + y`.

Comment: I didn't show all the code because it's too long, I have tried your code but it doesn't work, VB.net say there is error, he wait for a type of variable after your start as .. and the third line say me an error too ..

Comment: We don't see your errors. What do they say exactly? Usually VB is very good in describing the problem and shows its exact location. So read the error message carefully. I've added the type `Integer`, obviously VB cannot infer it.

Comment: Sorry i'm totally tired with this project.. Actually I don't understand your code and the error is just that after an As, VB asks me to declare the variable like As Integer or something else... I'm going to turn crazy with this project. I'm a beginner in VB, I started 2 months ago

Comment: What the .. Now I have no error but the code still doesn't work properly. I want to disable the 6 buttons of one player if his 6 buttons are filled with 0 but at the moment, if a button is filled with a 0, it's disabled and will never be enabled again.. Furthermore, all the others buttons are disabled but they have a number different of 0 ... Sorry if im not clear in my explanation, im french

Comment: You seem to have a conceptual problem. Can't solve it for you.